# Record detail view is not visible for partner users

Tags: profile, owd

Working on  custom object  let's call it as 'channel plan' owd is private. 
- Displaying few channel plan records based on code.

- Apex class is without sharing.

In community,I can able to view records, If I click on record links i can able to open detail page of few records and few records detail page  not able to open.

What's the issue here?

Q1: its related to record level issue or profile issue. Why iam not able to view record detail page for few records ?

Q2.if I dont have view access then I need throw insufficient privilage error so far i knw i can use user record object to  the read and edit accessibility of record.

Q3. I can able to view other records links , this means that I have read access,why I dont have view access?..

Q4.how read and view access are different ?or same?. I really got confused.. anyone please explain with me example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: its related to record level issue or profile issue. Why iam not able to view record detail page for few records ?

Record-level access is always the culprit when you can view some but not all records of a given object.

> Q2.if I dont have view access then I need throw insufficient privilage error so far i knw i can use user record object to the read and edit accessibility of record.

If you wish to show the user only records which they have permission to view, you should be running your Apex `with sharing`. That's exactly what it is designed to do: enforce record-level visibility rules. It is very rarely the correct solution to use a `without sharing` Apex class in user-facing functionality when the Org-Wide Default is set to `private`. That combination of features doesn't really make sense.

This is distinct from [enforcing CRUD and FLS in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS), which you also should likely be doing. That security is at the level of the object and the field, not the individual record.

> Q3. I can able to view other records links , this means that I have read access,why I dont have view access?..

The premise is incorrect here. If you are running an Apex class `without sharing`, it can query records that the running user does not have permission to see. If your Apex/Visualforce/Lightning then generates links to those records, the user will not be able to view them, because they do not have record-level access. You should avoid presenting links to inaccessible records to the user.

> Q4.how read and view access are different ?or same?. I really got confused.. anyone please explain with me example.

There is no such distinction in the record-level access layer of Salesforce's security model.

Comment: But one question is some record is I'm able to read it and but not able to edit.. why it's so?...

Comment: @Pavi I can't answer that. You need to review your sharing architecture, role hierarchy, and ownership to determine it. Clicking the Sharing button and reviewing the entries for that record can often provide a guidepost as to the reason.